# How can I get the MainActivity TextView from an public AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a MainActivity and an AsyncTask MyTask. They are separate classes. In MyTask, I want to update a TextView in MainActivity.

This seems easy if MyTask in a inner class of MainActivity because I can just call findViewById(). But now these two classes are separate.

So in my MainActivity I do this:

```
MyTask myTask=new MyTask();
Context context=this.getApplicationContext();
myTask.execute(context);
```

And my task is like this:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>
{
    TextView mText;
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {
        Context context=params[0];
        mText = (TextView) ((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.text);
...
    }
}
```

I know the "mText = (TextView) ((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.text);" is wrong but I haven't found the solution.

Any Hints

Thanks in Advance

Comment: there is a ClassCastException when I try to find the TextView

Comment: You're getting a ClassCastException because you're passing the Application Context instead of the Activity.  In your example, replace 'myTask.execute(context);' with 'myTask.execute(this);'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.  You can ignore the WeakReference if the task won't be long living:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  private WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;
  public MyTask(MainActivity activity) {
    mActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
  }

  public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    MainActivity activity = mActivity.get();
    if (activity != null) {
      TextView text = activity.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was literally searching for hours until I found this, big ups for the anwser !